# Virtual Box Pen Test Lab Set Up

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, centos, backtrack

So I’m trying to set up a pen test lab in virtual box on my windows 7 host.

I have 3 guest OS's installed:

1. BackTrack5
2. CentOS 5 Server/Snort (My Snortbox)
3. Windows XP (Unpatched)

I have 3 Ethernet adapters created IP'S

- 192.168.191.1
- 192.168.127.1
- 192.168.56.1

My goal is to use BackTrack5 to `nmap` the Windowss XP guest and have the CentOS Snort box sniff the network.

I’m new to networking and virtualization and I need help setting up my virtual network to get this to work. What should I do?

CentOS:

- **Adapter1:** NAT
- **Adapter2:** Host-only
- **Adapter3:** Internal Network

Backtrack:

- **Adapter1:** Internal Network

Windows XP:

- **Adapter1:**  Internal Network

Also factor in that I’m on a University network with a ridiculous firewall so I need to stay all within the host.

Comment: I am really curious about this because I will be doing similar stuff (hopefully) when I go to college next year..